# How to block access to the site directory through the browser?

Tags: assets, modx, modx-revolution

Good afternoon, how to close the root of the project from sharing through the browser?
[directory visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RuEe.png)

How to make a message about unavailability when trying to go to the root of the site through a browser, like here, and how to do it with modx tools?

[to be so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTmwq.png)

Comment: This should all be done in your webserver configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add next to `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files ~ "\assets$">  
 Order Allow,Deny  
 Deny from All  
</Files>
```

alternatively, you could use

```
Options -Indexes
```

into `.htaccess` inside `assets` folder

Comment: "Order Allow,Deny  
 Deny from All" -
This command hides the folder from external access, and also, some types of files, for example - ".pdf", become inaccessible. But ".jpg" files are still opened by direct link, as well as ".word" or ".rar" are downloaded.

But "Options -Indexes" work well - what i need, thanks